# how to read/write from a single file in ANSI C 89

Tags: c, file-io

A good example of what I'm trying to do could be seen in one of the following 2 samples:

read from a file char by char, at the start of a new line, prefix a line number (or something) manipulating the original file.

read from a file char by char, converting upper to lower, or lower to upper, manipulating the original file.

Only reason I ask is I've only ever done this by reading or writing a stream, not both operations on the same file (and never backtracking)

Also it seems I have 2 modes to operate in, insertion, and replacement.  Any guidance would help, documentation would be even better. (code samples backing them up would be much loved)

Comment: What have you done so far?  Have you opened the file?  Have you read the documentation of ANY of the reading functions (fread? read? fscanf? etc)?  What questions do you have about these functions?

Comment: well I've used these functions, but I'm so stupidly used to NI's labwindows CVI environment I'm forgetting ANSI stdio .

Comment: It doesn't make sense to read and write the same file, as its both more difficult and less safe. Much better to write to a second file and replace the first when you know writing it has succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

Converting case in place is pretty trivial:

1. Open file for update
2. read a block
3. modify the block
4. seek back to start of block
5. write block
6. repeat

This, however, only works because you're leaving the data the same length. Adding a line number to each line is a whole different story. To do it "in place", you basically have to read in the whole file, modify it in memory, then write it all back out. If it won't fit in memory, you'll have to modify it as you copy to another file, then copy that back to the first, or something on that order.

Comment: might as well do it the same way in both cases then.

Comment: "you're leaving the data the same length" - if you're not German ;-)

Comment: Btw, I'd say that procedure to replace a file is (1) write to a temporary file, (2) rename the original out of the way, (3) rename the temporary file to the original name, (4) delete the renamed old file. Gives you a shot at data recovery if something unpleasant happens, although that might well be beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: naw it's well within the scope.

Comment: @Steve: There's a good chance that won't do what you want under something with multiple hard links to a file though. The other links to the same file will retain their original content, which often isn't desired/desirable.

Comment: @Jerry: good point. For some reason I was thinking of a file that's in effect "owned" by the app modifying it. If the file belongs to the user, copy to a `.backup` if recovery is desirable, then do what you said.